# Masonry with different Bootstrap 3 responsive column classes

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-masonry

I have these columns and masonry is doing a great job at some of the stages, but it's failing to keep the last to columns at `col-xs-6` when the screen is "extra small".

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"></div>
```

**This is good at screen size medium+**
[image]

**This is good at screen size small**
[image]

**This is broken the last two columns should be 6 not 12**
[image]

Comment: I'm realizing that this is a width issue. I'm just still not sure how to have multiple responsive widths in a grid.

Comment: No time to fiddle but I believe bootstrap 3.0 itself will suffice in getting it done. Masonry is not required for this. In fact, it seems its masonry that is causing the spacing/width issue that is making the last 2 divs flow one below the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you have bootstrap and masonry doing things to these elements. Bootstrap is using media queries on the elements and changing their widths and stacking them differently when the window changes. Masonry is trying to do a similar thing by stacking the elements next to each other, because bootstrap is making the elements wider on the smaller sizes, masonry can't stack these properly.

ProTip: It would help greatly for debugging if you changed the elements background from the body background, that way you could see the actual sizes of the foreground elements.